# How to sort a list of strings by using the order of the items in another list?

Tags: sorting, dart

I want to sort a list of strings (with possibly duplicate entries) by using as ordering reference the order of the entries in another list. So, the following list is the list I want to sort

```
List<String> list =  ['apple','pear','apple','x','x','orange','x','pear'];
```

And the list that specifies the order is

```
List<String> order = ['orange','apple','x','pear'];
```

And the output should be

```
List<String> result = ['orange','apple','apple','x','x','x','pear','pear'];
```

Is there a clean way of doing this?

I don't understand if I can use list's `sort` and `compare` with the following problem. I tried using `map`, `iterable`, `intersection`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There might be a more efficient way but at least you get the desired result:

```
main() {
  List<String> list =  ['apple','pear','apple','x','x','orange','x','pear'];
  List<String> order = ['orange','apple','x','pear'];
  list.sort((a, b) => order.indexOf(a).compareTo(order.indexOf(b)));
  print(list);
}
```

Try it on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/01ceda394dde3e295d41)

The closure passed to `list.sort(...)` is a custom comparer which instead of comparing the passed item, compares their position in `order` and returns the result.

Using a map for better lookup performance:

```
main() {
  List<String> list =  ['apple','pear','apple','x','x','orange','x','pear'];
  List<String> orderList = ['orange','apple','x','pear'];
  Map<String,int> order = new Map.fromIterable(
      orderList, key: (key) => key, value: (key) => orderList.indexOf(key));
  list.sort((a, b) => order[a].compareTo(order[b]));
  print(list);
}
```

Try it on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/acdbb5162047a4945bb6)

Comment: Good solution. If performance becomes too bad (if `order` is a long list), you should first build a `Map` mapping as string to its index, and use that instead `of indexOf`.

Comment: This is a great solution, I just have one question. How would you also make items that don't exist in the order list also be sorted to the end of the final list. When i used this example I had extra values in my list that didn't exist in the order array. Those ones were basically ignored and ended up being in front of the some items in certain spots.
List<String> list =  [ "hello", "yoooo", "happy", "hello", "sad", "sad", "rwer"];
List<String> order = ["yoooo","sad"];